# command in bash script fails to use variable input

Tags: bash, variables, transactions, null

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

opid=$(./komodo-cli -ac_name=EXAMPLECOIN z_sendmany $fromAddress '[{"address":"'''$toAddress'''","amount":'''$sendAmount'''}]' 1 0)

echo $opid

txid=$(./komodo-cli -ac_name=EXAMPLECOIN z_getoperationstatus '["'$opid'"]' | jq -r '.[]' | jq -r '.result' | jq -r '.txid')

echo $txid
```

The intended goal of the bash script is run a command to send a transaction, take the operation ID of the transaction and use it in a command to get the transaction ID.

As it is now, the z_operationstatus command fails to use the opid variable and returns a null result.

opid will successfully send the transaction.

`echo $opid` outputs the opid properly. ex: opid-7a08d8e0-63ed-44b4-9c8a-79c90b8c460c

If I run txid by itself and replace `z_getoperationstatus '["'$opid'"]'` with `z_getoperationstatus '["'$1'"]'` and provide an opid when running, it will successfully print the correct txid.

The proper syntax for z_getoperationstatus is  `z_getoperationstatus '["opid..."]'` `but I added single quotes around`$opid` so the variable was recognized inside the already present single quotes. (not sure if this is correct or accounts for the issue)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There's an exclamation mark missing after the first character, the `#`. Just sayin'.

Comment: If you have `jq`, why are you creating JSON by concatenating variables?

Comment: @Roadowl thanks, but not the issue in the script. Just left it out here.

Comment: @Barmar I'm just using jq the best I know how to get only the desired results of the command output. z_operationstatus returns lots of data, but I only need txid as output and in other commands. I realize it might not be proper

Answer (score 0):

There may be a CR character at the end of `$opid`, try removing it.

```
opid=$(./komodo-cli -ac_name=EXAMPLECOIN z_sendmany $fromAddress '[{"address":"'''$toAddress'''","amount":'''$sendAmount'''}]' 1 0 | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: I tried that but no luck. echo still shows the proper opid from the transaction and null from z_getoperationstatus

Comment: You should use something like `echo "|$opid|"` so you can see if there's any whitespace around it.

Comment: Also try `echo "$opid" | od -c` to see if there are any other non-printing characters.

Comment: Here's the output with `echo "|$opid|"` :  

`|opid-a9cf03d2-d65e-4537-8185-8d65fe809564|
null`

Comment: Here's the output with `echo "$opid" | od -c` :  

`0000000   o   p   i   d   -   c   4   5   c   1   8   e   8   -   6   9
0000020   1   a   -   4   6   f   5   -   b   1   0   e   -   6   c   e
0000040   6   b   6   1   a   e   4   2   e  \n
0000052
null`

Comment: Nothing funny in there. `\n` comes from echo, it's not in the variable.

Comment: Bizarre.Where's the null coming from.

Comment: @Roadowl That's what I wonder, but it doesn't seem to be in the variable.

Comment: Maybe at this point time to ask: what is the output from `echo "|foo|" | od -c`.

Comment: Also: try `/bin/echo` in the script. And: output from `/bin/echo "$opid" | od -c`.

Comment: @Roadowl the output is `0000000   |   f   o   o   |  \n
0000006`

Comment: That output looks sane.

Comment: Sounds like you may have an alias for `echo`. But I don't think that should affect the command that's failing.

Comment: @Roadowl I added `/bin/echo` and `/bin/echo "$opid" | od -c`.  Output was: `opid-a1dffd22-4d2a-44bc-8fe0-19f3091dec7f
0000000   o   p   i   d   -   a   1   d   f   f   d   2   2   -   4   d
0000020   2   a   -   4   4   b   c   -   8   f   e   0   -   1   9   f
0000040   3   0   9   1   d   e   c   7   f  \n
0000052
null`

Comment: So the `null` is back. Maybe it's coming from your prompt? But I don't think it's relevant. I don't see any problem in the `od -c` output.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help so far, but is there anything else you think I can try? I've tested on other machines and face the same issue with the null output.